# Left hand glove and Right hand glove

Tags: permutations, combinations

There are n pairs of gloves and n men. In how many ways can each of the n men have a left hand of one pair and a right hand of another pair of gloves.

I thought its a simple question of derangements of n objects but I am not getting correct answer.

Comment: Are the men considered distinct?  Is each pair of gloves considered distinct?  Perhaps you are forgetting that *which* left-glove man $A$ receives matters before deranging the right gloves.

Comment: Well, you must first permute the left-handed gloves...and then take a derangement of the right-handed ones.  Thus, for two pair of gloves, the answer is $2$, not $1$.

Comment: @lulu Given answer is n! (n-1)! but I don't think it is correct.

Comment: Nor do I.  Works for $n=2,3$ but not $4$ or greater.  I'm with the posted solution, the answer is $n!\,D_n$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We assume the gloves are distinct. The left-hand gloves can be assigned in $n!$ ways. For each of these ways, the right-hand gloves can be assigned in $D_n$ ways.

Comment: Given answer is n! (n-1)! but I don't think it is correct.

Comment: @Mathematics: I cannot think of an interpretation that would make $n!(n-1)!$ right.